# Is it against the rules to solicit upvotes on third-party websites?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, rules

What is the policy for promoting Stack Overflow posts on third-party websites?

Examples:

- Creating a post on a social network that asks people to upvote your question.
- Creating a post on a social network that asks people to upvote your answer.
- Drawing attention to your question by linking to it on a third-party website.
- Drawing attention to your answer by linking to it on a third-party website.
- Asking people on a third-party website to answer your question.

Are there any restrictions to what users can do? If there are, how will users who break these rules be punished?

I'm just asking a question about this subject. I have no intention of doing anything shady.

Comment: Point 3, 4 and 5 - that's what the "Share" link is for, giving you a short url to *share* the question and answer. also i do seem to recall another link appearing to send questions to other people. ofcause with all the points if you start spamming people that's the quickest way for people to start putting you on their block lists

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense for SO to have policies for things that happen elsewhere that it can't control (nor reliably identify who did them).

Also, not every bad behaviour needs to be regulated by a policy. It's needless to say that sharing posts on social networks and asking people to upvote them isn't cool and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: As for the "drawing attention" part, go ahead. The share links aren't there just for show.

Comment: @Bart yeh, and we get badges for sharing posts