# Can I share my Stack Overflow profile with others?

Tags: discussion

I can't seem to find a share button or something like that. Is there a way for me to do this in a somewhat easy way?

Some friends and I often face similar problems and it might be easier to see their posts.

Comment: No, there is no such feature and please do not do that. Your friends might use this to shower you with upvotes which could result in their profiles being suspended. Please don't do it to your friends.

Comment: Considering you've asked no questions, and not answered any either, perhaps you are actually looking to share questions you found helpful to them or that you found perhaps while searching the problem they asked you about? Sharing is no different for [so] as with any other website in that regards; send them the URL...

Comment: I keep being surprised people don't notice the URLs immediately

Comment: What exactly do you want to share? The question title and body seem to be shot different things. What would the people you share with be able to do that others cannot?

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow (SO) isn't a social network app so you will not find here features available in apps like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. Instead here SO has features to make it easier to find and get notifications about new and updated content:

- Watch tags, see [tag-watching](/questions/tagged/tag-watching)
- Follow specific posts, see [follow-posts](/questions/tagged/follow-posts)
- Subscriptions, see  [subscriptions](/questions/tagged/subscriptions),  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subscription

Despite of the above, some web browsers already have built-in functions to share web pages, as well there are apps and web browser extensions focused on collecting and sharing web pages.

Contrary as happen on some common social media, here there aren't badges or other type of awards for profiles based on views, there aren't "friends", "followers" or alike metrics.

If you decide to share your profile by any mean, when doing that warn your friends that votes on this site should be based on the content, never on the author.

Related

- [Is it against the rules to solicit upvotes on third-party websites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331659/1595451)

Comment: Having your friends vote on your contributions is the quickest way for your account to be deleted and your friend(s) account suspended for voting irregularities. It will happen pretty quickly. It’s very easy to detect.